# Save data as modified input file name

Tags: matlab, file, parsing, filenames

I have a program that loads data from a .txt file and performs some curve fitting. The input file name for this example is `experiment09.txt`.

After processing I want to save a variable with the same input filename but appended with something like `_fit`. So my saved workspace variable in this case would be `experiment09_fit.txt`.

I have gotten this far in MATLAB:

```
buf = length(filename)
saveName = filename(1:buf-7)
```

which gives me a `saveName` of `experiment09` but I am at a loss as to how to add my chosen string on the end to make it `experiment09_fit`. Once I have a valid save name I will then just call

```
save(saveName, 'fittedValue', '-ASCII');
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
filename = 'experiment09.txt';
[pathstr, basename, ext] = fileparts(filename);
outname = [basename, '_fit', ext]; % will give 'experiment09_fit.txt'
```

Comment: That is sensational. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also use string concatenation for adding additional names to string variables.
For example,

```
    filename = 'experiment09.txt';
    [pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(filename);
    outputName1 = strcat(name,'_fit.');
    outputName = strcat(outputName1,ext);
```